# Input text type into array only last row

Tags: php, sql, arrays, input

i have some `text input`, to edit value of some subject like this :

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result2))
    {
       echo "<tr><td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Status'] . 
       "</td><td><input type=\"text\" size=\"4\" id=\"editmath[]\" name=\"editwater\" value=" . $row['math'] . ">
       </td><td><input type=\"text\" size=\"4\" id=\"editeng[]\" name=\"editfod\" value=" . $row['english'] .  ">
       </td><td><input type=\"text\" size=\"4\" id=\"editscie[]\" name=\"editmob\" value=" . $row['science'] . ">
        }
<Input type="Submit" value=" Next " name="submit_edit">
```

And in PHP i have this code :

```
if (isset($_GET['submit_edit'])) {
        $math[] = $_GET['editmath'];
        $eng[] = $_GET['editeng'];
        $scie[] = $_GET['editscie'];

        sql = "UPDATE student SET math = $math, english = $eng, science = $scie";
        $query = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

But when i try to `print_r` `math`, and `eng`, they only saved the last row. How to solve this problem?

```
Desired Output :
Math    English   Science
4       3        2
7       8        10
3       5        12
```

Comment: `name` should be in `array()` not `id`. You need to change the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here names are duplicating of inputboxes thats why this issue is occuring:

1)  Declare name of the input box as an array and in php loop through that array to store data:

2) use POST form instead of GET form type:

3) If you want to update record you also need to pass id along with all data

ex.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result2))
    {
       echo "<tr><td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Status'] . 
       "</td><td><input type=\"text\" size=\"4\" id=\"editmath[]\" name=\"editwater[]\" value=" . $row['math'] . ">
       </td><td><input type=\"text\" size=\"4\" id=\"editeng[]\" name=\"editfod[]\" value=" . $row['english'] .  ">
       </td><td><input type=\"text\" size=\"4\" id=\"editscie[]\" name=\"editmob[]\" value=" . $row['science'] . ">
        }
<Input type="Submit" value=" Next " name="submit_edit">
```

PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_edit'])) {
        for($i = 0; i < sizeof($_GET['editmath']) ; $i++) {
           $math = $_POST['editmath'][$i];
           $eng = $_POST['editeng'][$i];
           $scie = $_GET['editscie'][$i];

           $sql = "UPDATE student SET math = $math, english = $eng, science = $scie";
           $query = mysql_query($sql);
        }
}
```